# C# Tuple Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am trying to expand my usage of the dictionary and want to have multiple values for my  pairs.

I have had no issues with adding items to the dictionary with one .
I have tried to use Tuple as an option but cant seem to figure out how to extract a particular value.

this works:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> voc4 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 voc1.Add(key1, value);

 if (voc1.TryGetValue(result.Text.ToLower(), out string cmd))
 {
   ToSend(cmd);
 }
```

I tried to build a new dictionary with Tuple:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string ,string>> voc5 = new Dictionary<string,Tuple<string ,string>>();
voc5.Add(key1, new Tuple<string, string>(value,response));

if (voc5.TryGetValue(result.Text.ToLower(), out  string cmd))
 {//this is what I cant get working. I want to get the first value of thedictionary for 1 purpose and the other for a different purpose
 }
```

How can I get certain values based on the key and use them for different functions?
example would be:

```
 if (voc5.TryGetValue(result.Text.ToLower(), out  string cmd))// the first value
 {
   ToSend(value 1 from tuple).ToString();

   ToDisplay(value 2 from tuple).ToString();     
 }
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Not for nothing, but you have asked 7 questions and gotten 10 answers, but none of those answers are accepted. Accepting answers marks the question as answered ("RESOLVED").  Along with voting, it also helps other users find good answers/posts.  Its a way you can help others even if you are not in a position to post answers.  The [tour] explains it with pictures in about 2 mins

Comment: I apologize. I did not know to mark as resolved and helpful.

Comment: Instead of `out string cmd` (does that even compile?) it should be `out Tuple<string, string> tuple`, because that is the value type in `voc5` dictionary.

Comment: no it does not. That was the problem. I was unsure how to build the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the entire `Tuple<string, string>` instance out of your dictionary. Even if you'd only like to use one of the values, you have to fetch the entire tuple out.

After you retrieve the tuple use `ItemN` to access the elements.

```
if (voc5.TryGetValue(result.Text.ToLower(), out Tuple<string, string> cmd))
{
    ToSend(cmd.Item1).ToString();

    ToDisplay(cmd.Item2).ToString();   
}
```